# Django equivalent of Rails cancan and devise

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

I did projects with django back a while ago and switched to rails. I found lots of cool thing in rails. I need to add some features back to django project.

```
Are there  Django equivalent of Rails cancan and devise ?
Is there  Django equivalent of Rails scheduler gem?
```

**UPDATE**

For django permission framework I have to specify at each view something like

```
@permission_required('polls.can_vote')
def my_view
```

I prefer cancan's way I can manage all permissions in one place

```
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, :all      
      cannot :users, Swimming::Student
    end   
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Django’s builtin [permission framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) instead of `cancan` and `devise`. Does it fit your needs?

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is probably best thing for delaying and scheduling when working with Django. There is [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) package which integrates Celery with Django.

Comment: The good thing of rails scheduler gem like Rufus-scheduler is that just install the gem and get going (not other set up like db setting, queue setting ...), these things make deployment way complex.

Comment: Well, celery is VERY easy to use. But yes, you need to install some backend for it. Actually this will take just about 5-10 minutes. But if you want something simple then I'm sure there is alternatives. For example you can use uWSGI decorators (if you are on uWSGI) which provide very lightweight delaying and scheduling features. http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html

Answer (score 1):

Re permissions like cancan.

I'm using [djang-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules#advanced-features) and the end result looks/functions A LOT like cancan.

#### models/user.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ...
    def has_perm(self, name, obj=None):
        rset = self.__ruleset
        return rset.test_rule(name, self, obj)

    @property
    def __ruleset(self):
        from models.rules import (
            ManagerRuleSet, EmployeeRuleSet, GuestRuleSet
        )

        if self.group.is_manager:
            return ManagerRuleSet(self)
        elif self.group.is_employee:
            return EmployeeRuleSet(self)
        else:
            return GuestRuleSet(self)
```

#### models/rules.py

```
from rules import RuleSet


class InvalidUser(Exception):
    pass


class BaseRuleSet(RuleSet):
    def __init__(self, user):
        super()


class ManagerRuleSet(BaseRuleSet):
    def __init__(self, user):
        super()
        if user and not user.group.is_owner:
            raise InvalidUser("instantiated OwnerRuleSet with user in {} group",
                                    user.group.name)

        # Calendar permissions (pass appointment or schedule event)
        self.add_rule('calendar.can_view_calendar', rules.always_true)
        self.add_rule('calendar.can_manage_schedule',
                      is_own | has_accepted_invite)
```

#### example_view.py

```
def index(request, id):
    calendar = Calendar.objects.get(id=id)

    if not request.user.has_perm('calendar.can_manage_schedule', calendar):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[django-cancan](https://github.com/pgorecki/django-cancan) is an authorization library for Django, inspired by Rails cancan.

First, you define per-user abilities:

```py
def define_access_rules(user, rules):
    # Anybody can view published articles
    rules.allow('view', Article, published=True)

    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return 

    # ... grant other abilities to logged in user
```

then you can use it in a view:

```py
class ArticleDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    def get_queryset():
        # this is how you can retrieve all objects that current user can access
        qs = self.request.ability.queryset_for('view', Article)
        return qs

    def has_permission(self):
        article = self.get_object()
        # this is how you can check if user can access an object
        return self.request.ability.can('view', article)
```

or in a template:

```
{% if ability|can:"change"|subject:article %}
    <a href="{% url 'article_edit' pk=article.id %}">Edit article</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/) is a good package for handling Authentication and Password Reset stuff. It's an alternative to Devise in Django